# iframes...navigation panes

Tags: html, navigation, pane

So I have an iframe for my horizontal nav menu that is external.
the code I have is:

```
<p>
<iframe src="C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\project\nav_menu.html" name="sidebar_a" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="25" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<p>   
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
<p>
</iframe>
```

What am i supposed to do to fix this? When I click on a link, the iframe acts as a seperate website.

If an iframe is supposed to do that, How can i insert a navigation pane from an external source?